# Angular2 FormGroup patchValue error on undefined object value

Tags: mongodb, angular, typescript, undefined, formgroups

The problem I have been trying to solve relates to http requests and formgroups. I am attempting to patch in existing values to the form on an edit page.

The error comes when a value does not exist in the database (mongoDB), the value only exists on objects which they have been added to. The code below is my request, formgroup and patchValue.

```
        this.takeawayService.getByName(this.id).subscribe(data => {
            this.takeaway = data.takeaway[0];
            console.log(this.takeaway);
            this.formData = this.fb.group({
                address : ['', Validators.required],
                city : ['', Validators.required],
                county : ['', Validators.required],
                postCode : ['', [Validators.required,
                    Validators.pattern('[A-Za-z]{1,2}[0-9Rr][0-9A-Za-z]? [0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Zabd-hjlnp-uw-z]{2}')]],
                bio : ['', Validators.required],
                image : '',
                _id : '',
                cuisines: [],
                isPublic: [false, Validators.required],
                'openingHours': fb.group({
                    'monday': fb.group({
                        opened: [false],
                        open: [''],
                        close: ['']
                    })

                })


            });

            this.formData.patchValue({
                address: this.takeaway.address,
                city: this.takeaway.city,
                county: this.takeaway.county,
                postCode: this.takeaway.postCode,
                bio: this.takeaway.bio,
                image: this.takeaway.image,
                _id: this.takeaway._id,
                cuisines: this.takeaway.cuisines,
                isPublic: this.takeaway.isPublic,
                openingHours: {
                    monday:{
                        opened: this.takeaway.openingHours.monday.opened,
                        open: null,
                        close: null
                    }
                }

            });
```

The error I receive when attempting to patch a value which has not been given back by the request is 'TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.takeaway.openingHours.monday')'.

I have attempted using ternaries to solve this with no luck ( openingHours.monday.opened ? openingHours.monday.opened : false ). Any help would be amazing. I have tried searching for anything simular to my problem with no luck.

EDIT:
I have attempted to use a template with my formgroup by setting some fields as optional but no luck. The value is still undefined.

```
export interface Takeaway {
   address: String,
   city: String,
   county: String,
   postCode: String,
   bio: String,
   image: String,
   _id: String,
   cuisines: [String],
   isPublic: Boolean,
   openingHours?: {
       monday?: {
           opened?: Boolean,
           open?: Date,
           close?: Date,

       }
   }
```

Comment: Is any value retrieving for  this.takeaway.openingHours.monday?  If not you can try   this.takeaway.openingHours.monday?  this.takeaway.openingHours.monday.opened:false

Comment: @Dimuthu I am able to get it working if I check to see if this.takeaway.openingHours ?. I was worried that this was not the right way to go about it. I also tried using a interface for my expected data(as shown above in my edit) but no luck.